# how to check if any checkbox is checked in grid,wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have number of checkboxs in grid,i have to check if any check box is checked then it will print name like- MsgBox ("CheckboxName").

```
<Grid Height="179" Width="290" Name="Checksum_Collection" >
        <CheckBox Content="Alder32" Height="20" Name="Alder32CheckBox" />
        <CheckBox Content="BsdChecksum" Height="20" Name="BsdChecksumCheckBox"/> 
        <CheckBox Content="CRC16" Height="20" Name="CRC16CheckBox"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Damm" Height="20" Name="DammCheckBox"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Fletcher" Height="20" Name="FletcherCheckBox" />
        <CheckBox Content="LRC" Height="20" Name="LRCCheckBox"  />
        <CheckBox Content="Luhn" Height="20" Name="LuhnCheckBox"/>
        <CheckBox Content="MD5 Hash" Height="20" Name="MD5CheckBox"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The answers posted up till now lets you check every checkBox. Instead, were you looking to call `MsgBox("name")` only when a checkbox is checked, and then display that particular checkbox's name only?

Comment: @Vanlalhriata : Yes exactly ,if i close window without checked any check box, then msg is display only one time MsgBox("No check box is Checked").if any one or more select then it desplay MsgBox("ChecckBox.Name").

Comment: Ah. I have misundertood your question, and you have probably misunderstood my comment :) You should attach an event handler to the closing event of the window containing your checkboxes. Put the code in one of the answers in the handler. Check on the green tickmarks on one of the answers if this solves your problem. Reply if it doesn't

Comment: @Vanlalhriata: The Msg is display 8 times on closing the window without select any checkbox(There is 8 checkbox). but i want it display for once time. see this code---                           Dim child As Controls.CheckBox
        For Each child In Checksum_Collection.Children
            If (child.IsChecked = True) Then
            Else
                MsgBox("Please select any algorithm")
            End If
        Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
foreach(var child in Checksum_Collection.Children)
{
    if(child.getType() == typeof(CheckBox))
    {
        if(child.IsChecked)
            MsgBox ("CheckboxName");    // or do whatever u want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (var checkBox in Checksum_Collection.Children
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(cb => (bool)cb.IsChecked))
{
    var name = checkBox.Name;
    Trace.TraceInformation("{0} is checked", name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the checked and unchecked events attached to the check box and in these events add/remove selected/unselected items from a collection like hashtable

```
<CheckBox Content="Item 1" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"    Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

and in the code:

```
List<string> SelectedItems = new List<string>();
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItems.Add((e.OriginalSource as CheckBox).Name.ToString());
    }
    private void CheckBox_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItems.Remove((e.OriginalSource as CheckBox).Name.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

XAML

```
<dxe:CheckEdit IsChecked="{Binding RowData.Row.IsSelected}" Checked="CheckEdit_Checked" 
 Unchecked="CheckEdit_Checked"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Code Behind

Have a class level: isAnyChecked = 0;

```
private void CheckEdit_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (e.RoutedEvent.Name == "Checked")
{
    isAnyChecked += 1;
}
else if(e.RoutedEvent.Name =="Unchecked")
{
    isAnyChecked -= 1;
    if(isAnyChecked == 0)
}
}
```

Comment: If you format your code to eliminate scrolling, you make it easier for others to read.